# A computer represents information in groups of 64 bits. How many different integers can be represented in BCD code?

Tags: bit, bcd

This from my Interview-MCQ module:

> A computer represents information in groups of 64 bits. How many
>   different integers can be represented in BCD code?

The given answer is 10<sup>16</sup>, however no explanation is provided, I was just wondering if somebody could help me understand the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCD is [binary coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).  In BCD, every 4 bits is used to represent a single digit from 0 to 9.  So if you have 64 bits, that gives you 64/4 = 16 decimal digits, which means you can have 10^16 different integers.